# What is the difference betwen two methods?

Tags: javascript, oop

I can call parse method of Date object directly as follows:

```
    alert(Date.parse("March 21, 2012"));
```

However I cannot do this:

```
    alert(Date.getTime()); // TypeError: Date.getTime is not a function
```

That is how I get it working:

```
    alert(new Date().getTime()); // works well
```

So why can't I call Date.getTime() directly like Date.parse()?

Underlying Question: I have written a class and I want to use some of its methods directly like Date.parse() above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, JavaScript uses prototypes to defined instance methods.  You can however defined static methods as shown below.  I am not trying to define the whole `Date` object here, but rather show how its instance and static functions are defined.

```
// constructor defined here
function Date() {
    // constructor logic here
}

// this is an instance method
DateHack.prototype.getTime = function() {
    return this.time_stamp;
}

// this method is static    
Date.parse = function(value) {
    // do some parsing
    return new Date(args_go_here);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`getTime` is in `Date.prototype`, which is used when constructing `new Date()` objects.

`parse` is in `Date` itself, and thus is called directly rather than from a constructed object.

Here's [a post about JavaScript prototypes](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/) for your reading pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

In object-oriented programming, the former is called a *static* method, whereas the latter is called an *instance* method.  An instance method requires an instance of the object has been instantiated (thus the `new Date()` call is necessary).  Static methods do not have this requirement.

> Underlying Question: I have written a class and I want to use some of its methods directly like Date.parse() above.

After you have written your class, to add static methods, you will want to do:

```
MyClass.myStaticFunction = function() {
    // Contents go here.
}
```

Comment: I defined all methods inside constructor

Comment: ...so I can only use them only after creating an object, right? I thought that would be same defining a function inside the constructor or like above.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Class() {
    this.foo = function() { return 123; };
}
Class.bar = function() { return 321; };

Class.bar(); // 321

( new Class ).foo(); // 123
```